# Удаление идентичных элементов в Dictionary

Tags: c#

```
Dictionary(int key,list<x> y)
```

В `y` есть элементы `name`
Если `y.name != ключу` в котором лежит лист, то удали этот элемент из листа.
Нужно сделать пробег по всему `Dictionary`.
Я пробовал `foreach`,но он ругается на то, что, когда удаляешь элемент листа, пишет что лист модифицирован.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class list
{
  public int name { get; set; }
}

Dictionary<int, list> dict = new Dictionary<int, list>();

dict[1] = new list() { name = 100 };
dict[2] = new list() { name = 2 };
dict[3] = new list() { name = 300 };

foreach (var mismatch in dict.Where(item => item.Key != item.Value.name).ToList())
{
  dict.Remove(mismatch.Key);
}
```

Comment: Там нужно вроде бы `!=`.

Comment: @VladD да, так тоже можно :)

Answer (score 6):

Ещё один вариант, в функциональном стиле:

```
dict = dict.Where(item => item.Key == item.Value.name)
           .ToDictionary(item => item.Key, item => item.Value);
```

Вы создаёте полностью новый словарь, и заменяете старый на новый, так что никакой модификации нет.

---

При этом вы подменяете объект, так что те, у кого была своя ссылка на ваш объект, будут работать со старой версией словаря. Это может быть то или не то, что вы хотите, в зависимости от того, как устроена ваша программа. (Например, если другие пользователи вашего словаря работают с ним, они могут не рассчитывать на то, что словарь поменяется.)

Comment: но теперь-то `==`

Comment: @Igor: И правда :)

Comment: может, упомянуть о возможных ссылках на старый словарь в других местах?

Comment: @Igor: Хорошая мысль, да. Так и сделал, спасибо!

Comment: Что интересно, этот вариант будет быстрее соседнего если нужно удалить много элементов и медленнее, если мало. Если удалять половину элементов - то варианты равны по скорости.

Comment: @Андрей: Ну и плюс разная семантика: там изменяется текущий экземпляр, а тут создаётся новый.